# Android Download manager

Tags: java, android

i used a custom library for my android download manager 
https://github.com/smanikandan14/ThinDownloadManager

It seems i have a problem in 
onProgress method

i tried changing text of the textview in the method onProgress but i doesn't change...but if i try to change the text in ondownloadcomplete...it works
i think it is some thread issue

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    downloadbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_download);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse("http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4");
    Uri destinationUri = Uri.parse(this.getExternalCacheDir().toString()+"/test.mp4");
    final   DownloadRequest downloadRequest = new DownloadRequest(downloadUri)
            .addCustomHeader("Auth-Token", "YourTokenApiKey")
            .setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy())
            .setDestinationURI(destinationUri).setPriority(DownloadRequest.Priority.HIGH)
            .setDownloadListener(new DownloadStatusListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDownloadComplete(int id) {
                    textView.setText("complete");
                }

                @Override
                public void onDownloadFailed(int id, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(int id, long totalBytes, long downlaodedBytes, int progress) {

                }


            });

    downloadbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             ThinDownloadManager downloadManager;
            downloadManager = new ThinDownloadManager();
            int downloadId = downloadManager.add(downloadRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. There is no "question" in your post. This "custom library" looks like it has its issues... still, you chose it. What is the problem here? Your `onProgress` is blank, and `onDownloadFailed` could have happened and you keep "waiting for it to finish successfully.

Comment: it is finishing successfully as i can access the downloaded file in the downloaded location and the onProgress is blank because any code inside onProgress is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an UIthread inside onProgress method  and it solved the problem.